# Selective update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, junction-table

I've created a junction table like this one:

http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/822/kantotype.png

I was trying to figure out a query that could able to select some rows - based on the `PokémonID` - and then updating only the first or second row after the major "**filtering**".

For example:

Let's suppose that I would like to change the value of the TypeID from the second row containing `PokémonID = 2`. I cannot simply use `UPDATE KantoType SET TypeID = x WHERE PokémonID = 2`, because it will change both rows!

I've already tried to use subqueries containing `IN`,`EXISTS` and `LIMIT`, but with no success.

Comment: You need to provide information about the Pokemon and Type tables and explain why you have two records in the KantoType table per Pokemon.

Comment: Can you not do a WHERE PokemonID = 2 AND TypeID = 18 for the second row? If not, how do you order your rows - what's the "second" row and what's the "first" row? Ordered by TypeID?

Comment: Actually is very simple. If you ever played pokémon, you know that a pokémon can have 1 or 2 types. However, you can note that, in the very first table I provided, I've added 2 types for every pokémon (note: we can consider the TypeID as a default for no second type).
About the rows' order, there isn't actually one: It all depends on the pokémon you are considering. For example, you may 2 pokémons which have the same type (steel and rock, for example), but the first pokemon may have its primary type as rock and the other as steel...

Comment: Actually, I intend to use this query in a C# project. Here are some useful links:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/708/pokmonform.png/
http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/401/diagramf.png

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't played Pokemon. There are two options. Either you know the type you're updating, in which case you can use filter on both PokemonID AND TypeID in your query. Or if you don't know the TypeID but simple want to update the "second" row - then you need to define how rows are ordered (for example, by TypeID ascending/descending, or some other column), so you can tell SQL Server which row is the second. The SQL for the second option has been provided by Mahmoud Gamal.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what are your trying to do. However, you can `UPDATE` with `JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE 
SET k1.TypeID = 'somethng' -- or some value from k2
FROM KantoType k1
INNER JOIN
(
   Some filtering and selecting
) k2 ON k1.PokémonID = k2.PokémonID 
WHERE k1.PokémonID = 2;
```

**Or:** if you want to `UPDATE` only the two rows that have `PokémonID = 2` you can do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS 
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TypeID) rownum
   FROM KantoType
   WHERE PokemonID = 2
) 
UPDATE c 
SET  c.TypeID = 5
FROM CTE c
WHERE c.rownum = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea769/4)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest something like this if you just need to update a single line in your table:

```
UPDATE kantotype
SET 
  type = 2
WHERE pokemon = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kantotype k2 
                WHERE kantotype.type > k2.type
                   AND kantotype.pokemon = k2.pokemon)
```

It would be easier to get the first or last item of the table if you had unique identifier field in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure even if you are trying to update the row with PokemenID =2 by doing a **major filtering** on TypeID... So just out of assumptiong (big one), you can give a try on `Case`

```
UPDATE yourtable a
LEFT JOIN youtable b on a.pokeid = b.pokeid
SET a.typeid = (CASE
   WHEN a.typeid < b.typeid THEN yourupdatevalue
   WHEN a.typeid > b.typeid THEN someothervalue   
   ELSE a.typeid END);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the pokemon ID and the type id then just add both to the where clause of your query.

```
UPDATE KantoType 
SET TypeID = x 
WHERE PokémonID = 2
AND TypeID=1
```

If you don't know the type ID, then you need to provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish.  It's not clear why you don't have this information.

Perhaps think about what is the unique identifier in your data set.